# NoSuchMethodException: com.x.y.z.j.h1.inflate [class android.view.LayoutInflater] - view binding extension

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have a view binding extension for activity. Here is the implementation :

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewBinding> Activity.viewBinding() = ActivityViewBindingDelegate(T::class.java)

class ActivityViewBindingDelegate<T : ViewBinding>(private val bindingClass: Class<T>) : ReadOnlyProperty<Activity, T> {
    /**
     * initiate variable for binding view
     */
    private var binding: T? = null

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Activity, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        binding?.let { return it }

        /**
         * inflate View class
         */
        val inflateMethod = bindingClass.getMethod("inflate", LayoutInflater::class.java)

        /**
         * Bind layout
         */
        val invokeLayout = inflateMethod.invoke(null, thisRef.layoutInflater) as T

        /**
         * Set the content view
         */
        thisRef.setContentView(invokeLayout.root)

        return invokeLayout.also { this.binding = it }
    }
}
```

When i run my app in debug variant, everything works fine.

When i run my app in release variant, at runtime when activity launching i get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.x.y.z.j.h1.inflate [class android.view.LayoutInflater]
```

isMinifyEnabled = true
isShrinkResources = true

I must obfuscate my activity. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Comment: Yes, I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bindingClass.getMethod("inflate", LayoutInflater::class.java)
```

and

```
bindingClass.getMethod("bind", View::class.java)
```

are obfuscated with R8 obfuscation. Thus I get this exception. We should exclude obfuscation for inflate and bind methods.

Thus the following must be added to use the view binding extension function for fragment and activity

```
-keep class com.sample.myapplication.databinding.* {
    public static ** inflate( ** );
    public static ** bind( ** );
}
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add in proguard-rules

```
-keepclassmembers class ** implements androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding {
    public static ** bind(***);
    public static ** inflate(***);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep,allowoptimization class * implements androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding {
   public static *** bind(android.view.View);
   public static *** inflate(...);
 }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**